# Could rakshasas be detected by paladin’s Divine Sense?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, class-feature, paladin

Rakshasas have limited magic immunity which protect them from being detected by magic of 6th (or smaller) level.

But paladin’s Divine Sense ability is not a magic at all.

Does it mean that even 1st lvl paladin could detect rakshasas with it?

Comment: A corresponding /r/DnD thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/8bb5m7/can_rakshasa_be_detected_by_divine_sense/

Answer (score 30):

## Divine Sense can detect Rakshasas

The text of the Rakshasas's Limited Magic Immunity reads:

> The rakshasa can't be affected or detected by **spells** of 6th level or lower unless it wishes to be.

As you noted, the Paladin's Divine Sense class feature is not a spell:

> The presence of strong evil registers on your senses like a noxious odor, and powerful good rings like heavenly music in your ears. As an action, you can open your awareness to detect such forces.

So Divine Sense is not affected by Limited Magic Immunity, the Paladin can detect the Rakshasas